# Bash - creating multiple lists files from one file list

Tags: bash, list, for-loop

The directory contains `x` files. I get a list of files. I want to split this list into a larger number of `n` lists, which would have a limited number of elements.

Examples:

```
files=$( ls -d /*.csv | sort )
echo $files

/100347_111111.csv
/111301_111111.csv
/111301_222222.csv
/256467_111111.csv
/256467_222222.csv
/256467_333333.csv
/256467_444444.csv
/256467_555555.csv
/256467_666666.csv
/256467_777777.csv
```

From the resulting list I want to create 3 lists. The lists must not have more than 4 elements. The first list should be composed of the first 4 elements from the `files`, the other list should contain the following 4 elements, the third list should contain the remaining elements.

```
n1
/100347_111111.csv
/111301_111111.csv
/111301_222222.csv
/256467_111111.csv

n2
/256467_222222.csv
/256467_333333.csv
/256467_444444.csv
/256467_555555.csv

n3
/256467_666666.csv
/256467_777777.csv
```

Does someone can help, how to create lists as described above?

Comment: I do not know where to start. I think the solution is by using for loop. But I do not really know where to start, I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: @Amessihel. do you honestly think OP is thinking split or file?

Comment: I do not want to split rows in the file. I want the file name list to be subdivided into sublists.

Comment: there is no need for lists, lists are almost never used in shell. what do you want to do with lists?

Comment: @perreal: maybe not. It's an example (you solved it this way). Another search would be with those [keywords](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bash+for+loop+number): `bash` `for` `loop` `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILES=( `ls -d * | sort`)
echo "${FILES[@]:0:4}"
```

Loop of 4

```
count=4
for i in $(seq 0 $(( ${#FILES[@]}/$count - 1 ))) ;
   do  
     echo "######## Set" $i "#######"; 
     echo "${FILES[@]:$(( i * $count )):$count }" ; 
   done
```

Comment: @amessihel modified

Answer (score 1):

An example which may be reinventing the wheel:

```
\ls -1 |
    {
        n=0
        cr=""
        pack=1
        while read -r l
        do
            mod=$(($n % 4))
            if [[ "$mod" == "0" ]]
            then
                echo -e "$cr"n"$pack:"
            fi
            echo $l
            n=$((n + 1))
            pack=$((pack + 1))
            cr="\n";
        done
    }
```

Here, we use the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator to check if a new pack is about to be displayed (`n modulo 4 = 0` if `n` is a multiple of `4`).

I used curly brackets `{}` to put var initialization and the while loop in the same environment (other wise `while` won't be able to retrieve `n`, `pack` and `cr` variables).

Answer (score 0):

Try split:

```
ls -d /*.csv | sort | split -l 4 -d
```

this will create files x01 x02... containing maximum 4 lines.